# How to update KEY_ROWID after deleting a row in SQLite database

Tags: android

How can I update the KEY_ROWID number in SQLite database after deleting a row from the database? 
CASE 1:
For example, if I have five rows in the database, maximum KEY_ROWID is 5 at that time. I delete all rows in the table. Then I add new rows, at that time KEY_ROWID doesn't start from 1 again, it starts from 6. How can I reset KEY_ROWID to start from 1 again.
CASE 2:
If I delete row three, now only four rows in the table and row 4 change to 3 and 5 change to 4.
How can I make these changes in the program?
Do I need to program it for these changes or is there any setting in SQLite to update KEY_ROWID after deleting a row?
Thanks

Comment: That's an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) (question about an attempted solution rather than the actual problem); describe what you are trying to achieve by doing this instead.

Answer (score 0):

[You can reset the sequences if you're deleting all data;](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/0a372/1)

```
DELETE FROM test;
DELETE FROM sqlite_sequence WHERE name='test';
```

As for renumbering primary keys when there is still data in the table, I'd *sincerely* advise against it, since any foreign keys that reference your table will be broken.

Comment: If you're _really_ sure you want to renumber the table, here are [two](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/96d04/1) [options](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/fd1d5/1)

Comment: I am just a newbie in database. I can't figure out your sample. And the way in programming also looks different from SQLite Android format. Do you have sample for Android programming format? I really want to renumber the primary keys.

Answer (score -1):

The solution is that rewriting the table with a new array or list ;

reWriteTable is will allow automatic sorting of rows.

```
private void reWriteTable(){
    if(db.listOfDate().size()!=0){
        String[] name =new String[db.listOfDate().size()] ;
        String[] note=new String[db.listOfDate().size()] ;
        String[] date =new String[db.listOfDate().size()];
        String[] time =new String[db.listOfDate().size()];
        String[] total =new String[db.listOfDate().size()];

        for(int i=0;i<db.listOfDate().size();i++) {
            String currentString =db.listOfDate().get(i) ; // 0,1,2,3
            separated = currentString.split("-");  //Take words between "-" from Database 
            name[i]=separated[1];
            note[i]=separated[2];
            date[i]=separated[3];
            time[i]=separated[4];
            total[i]=separated[1]+"-"+separated[2]+"-"+separated[3]+"-"+separated[4];
        }
        db.deleteTable();
        //db=new Database(MainActivity.this);
        for(int i=0;i<total.length;i++) {
            Log.d("TAG",String.valueOf(total.length)+"  "+total[i]);
            String currentString =total[i] ; // 0,1,2,3
            separated = currentString.split("-");  //Take words between "-" from Database 
            name[i]=separated[0];
            note[i]=separated[1];
            date[i]=separated[2];
            time[i]=separated[3];
            // total[i]=separated[1]+"-"+separated[2]+"-"+separated[3]+"-"+separated[4];
            db.addData(name[i],note[i],date[i],time[i]);
        }
    }

}
```

Define deleting table in Database.java ;

```
 protected void deleteTable(){
        SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.execSQL(" drop table if exists " + TABLO_UYGULAMALAR + ";");
        onCreate(db);

    }
```