# How to get rid of gaps in rowid numbering after deleting rows?

Tags: sql, sqlite

Table `tmp` :

```
CREATE TABLE if not exists tmp (
            id             INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
            name            TEXT NOT NULL);
```

I inserted 5 rows. `select rowid,id,name from tmp;` :

| rowid | id | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | a |
| 2 | 2 | b |
| 3 | 3 | c |
| 4 | 4 | d |
| 5 | 5 | e |

Now I delete rows with id 3 and 4 and run above query again:

| rowid | id | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | a |
| 2 | 2 | b |
| 5 | 5 | e |

`rowid` is not getting reset and leaves holes. Even after `vacuum` it doesn't reset `rowid`.

I want :

| rowid | id | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | a |
| 2 | 2 | b |
| 3 | 5 | e |

How to achieve above output?

Comment: The purpose of an ID is to identify a row. This is no longer possible when you change IDs.

Comment: That's an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) (question about an attempted solution rather than the actual problem); describe what you are trying to achieve by doing this instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I assume you already know a little about `rowid`, since you're asking about its interaction with the `VACUUM` command, but this may be useful information for future readers:

`rowid` is [a special column available in all tables](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid) (unless you use `WITHOUT ROWID`), used internally by sqlite. A `VACUUM` is supposed to rebuild the table, aiming to reduce fragmentation in the database file, and [may change the values of the `rowid` column](https://sqlite.org/lang_vacuum.html). Moving on.

Here's the answer to your question: `rowid` is *really*  special. So special that if you have an `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`, it becomes an alias for the `rowid` column. From the docs on [rowid](https://sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid):

> With one exception noted below, if a rowid table has a primary key that consists of a single column and the declared type of that column is "INTEGER" in any mixture of upper and lower case, **then the column becomes an alias for the rowid**. Such a column is usually referred to as an "integer primary key". A PRIMARY KEY column only becomes an integer primary key if the declared type name is exactly "INTEGER". Other integer type names like "INT" or "BIGINT" or "SHORT INTEGER" or "UNSIGNED INTEGER" causes the primary key column to behave as an ordinary table column with integer affinity and a unique index, not as an alias for the rowid.

This makes your primary key faster than it would've been otherwise (presumably because there's no lookup from your primary key to `rowid`):

> The data for rowid tables is stored as a B-Tree structure containing one entry for each table row, using the rowid value as the key. This means that retrieving or sorting records by rowid is fast. Searching for a record with a specific rowid, or for all records with rowids within a specified range is **around twice as fast** as a similar search made by specifying any other PRIMARY KEY or indexed value.

Of course, when your primary key is an alias for `rowid`, it would be terribly inconvenient if this could change. Since `rowid` is now aliased to *your application data*, it would not be acceptable for sqlite to change it.

Hence, this little note in the [VACUUM docs](https://sqlite.org/lang_vacuum.html):

> The VACUUM command may change the ROWIDs of entries in any tables **that do not have an explicit INTEGER PRIMARY KEY.**

If you *really really really* absolutely need the `rowid` to change on a `VACUUM` (I don't see why -- feel free to discuss your reasons in the comments, I may have some suggestions), you can avoid this aliasing behavior. Note that it will decrease the performance of any table lookups using your primary key.

To avoid the aliasing, and degrade your performance, you can use `INT` instead of `INTEGER` when defining your key:

> **A PRIMARY KEY column only becomes an integer primary key if the declared type name is exactly "INTEGER".** Other integer type names like "INT" or "BIGINT" or "SHORT INTEGER" or "UNSIGNED INTEGER" causes the primary key column to behave as an ordinary table column with integer affinity and a unique index, not as an alias for the rowid.

Comment: I am not actually keen to run vacuum but I tried with vacuum as some blogs say it. I just want final output with new rowids as I mentioned in the question. Does not matter if I have to run vacuum or by any other trick. Do you know any other way to achieve this except changing column type it to INT?

Comment: But *why* do you need the id:s to change? I don't understand why that would be useful to you.

Comment: I require old id to new id mapping. So after deletion I want to regenerated row ids. After that row ids will be new ids without holes and old ids would be in actual "id" column

Comment: Then just do a query, `ORDER BY id ASC`, and use your own counter when looping over the results on the Java side to get an ordinal. Still not sure why you need it -- seems like persistent id:s would be better than having them shift around...

Comment: I could do that. But I need to use old-new id mapping in other query only and not in code.

Comment: I still don't understand why you'd ever need that. But yeah, you have a way to do it up there in my answer.

Comment: I tried making column as INT primary key and then did vacuum but still behavior doesnt change. It is giving the same behavior as INTEGER was giving. Do I need to do anything else?

Comment: A PRIMARY KEY column only becomes an integer primary key if the declared type name is exactly "INTEGER" --> and also NOT NULL

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution for some case. I don't know why, but this worked.
1.Rename column "id" to any other name (not PRIMARY KEY) or delete this column because you have already "rowid".

```
CREATE TABLE if not exists tmp (
            my_i             INTEGER NOT NULL,
            name            TEXT NOT NULL);
```

2.Insert 5 rows in it.

select rowid,* from tmp;

```
rowid  my_i    name
1      1      a
2      2      b
3      3      c
4      4      d
5      5      e
```

3.Delete rows with rowid 3 and 4 and run above query again.

```
DELETE FROM tmp WHERE rowid = 3;
DELETE FROM tmp WHERE rowid = 4;
select rowid,* from tmp;
rowid  my_i    name
1      1        a
2      2        b
5      5        e
```

4.Run SQL

```
VACUUM;
```

5.Run SQL

```
select rowid,* from tmp;
```

The output:

```
rowid my_i  name
1      1    a
2      2    b
3      5    e
```

Answer (score 0):

You must define all data from database to new array / list.After that you must delete table and rewrite all data from array / list to database .
Check it ;

https://stackoverflow.com/a/57862686/8363647

Answer (score 0):

I don't get why there is so much hesitance in illustrating the answer here.
If there are any tips or specific examples y'all could provide on how or why or when to be weary of usage, we'd all appreciate it.

Here is how I solved my problem, similar to OP.

```
c.execute(f"DELETE FROM customers WHERE rowid = ({id})")
print(f"deleted {id}")
conn.commit()
c.execute("VACUUM")
conn.close()
```

Comment: Are you sure you replied to the right post? This just repeats the question: "... *I delete rows with id 3 and 4 and* ..." "*Even after doing vacuum, it still doesnt reset rowid* ...".